# GET error when trying to post to WCF Web Service via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf

I have an mvc project where I'm trying to post to a WCF Service I created via a web form and AJAX call. I'm getting an error when it's hitting the WebService and all it says is GET.

Here's an image of it:
[image]

Here's what the important part of the AJAX looks like:

```
    var songRequest = {
        Title: 'New Slang',
        Artist: 'The Shins',
        Genre: 'Indie',
        Difficulty: 'Easy',
        id: 11
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#createSong").on("click", "#saveSong", function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:17476/SongRESTService.svc/json/PostJson/',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(songRequest),
                method: "POST"
            }).done(function (response, b, c) {
                console.log(response, b, c);

            }).error(function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
                alert("There was an error saving the song. Please try again.");
            });

        });
    });
```

Normally that data would be generated from the form, but I just hard coded it for testing purposes.

The webservice part looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                       UriTemplate = "json/PostJson/")]
    String PostJson();
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Network tab error:
[image]

Comment: We need to see the actual error, go to the network tab in Chrome and look at the request/response.

Comment: Did you enable `JSONP` or `CORS` on your service side? You don't seem to have given the error message. Looks like you are violating the same origin policy with this AJAX request.

Comment: DavidG, I added the picture but I don't think it provides much more info

Comment: Darin, I don't think so. I've googled a ton about that but haven't found where to enable that on the service side.

Comment: Yes it does, it says HTTP 405 which means the service does not accept the HTTP method you are using.

Comment: Is this something I'll need to fix in the Web.Config?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `dataType: 'jsonp'` and trying to make a POST request which doesn't make any sense because JSONP works only with GET requests (at least in jQuery's implementation). You might consider using [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) instead if you need to use the POST verb. For this you could globally enable CORS on your server by adding the following to your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Now get rid of this `dataType: 'jsonp'` from your AJAX call.

Another possibility if you are using IIS is to add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```